# Adding custom information to Files tab

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

Using the lightning:fileUpload tag recently released, the file attaches itself to the files tab which is under all related tab (see pictures below).

[image]

[image]

Can the file be attached anywhere else apart from the files tab? If not can we associate information with the attached file such as some text within the files tab? If non of these are an option would it be easier to create a attach file component?

My task is to attach some information with a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File is a Salesforce object. when you attach a file to a record - you actually create a new file record and set it's parent Id to the record that you are attaching to.

So to answer your questions:

1. uploading a file always adds a file to the file list of the object - you can view this file list from the "Related Lists" component or the "Related List - Single" component - both available in the AppBuilder, and you can add them to whatever tab you want:

[image]

2. Underneath the File object there are a few objects that handle and manage files, there is one object names ContentVersion - you can add fields to this standard object and then save extended data on each file. I don't think that the `lightning:fileUpload` component supports additional fields, but you can set them from the standard layout:

[image]

[image]